# netlogo export to csv

Tags: csv, netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo so probably it's a dumb question. 
while I'm trying to export turtles, patches, global variables to separated CSV files, this one works:

`csv:to-file "turtles.csv" [ (list xcor ycor color shape) ] of turtles`

but the following two don't:

`csv:to-file "patches.csv" [ (list xcor ycor cluster-number) ] of patches`
error: this code can't be run by a patch, only a turtle

`csv:to-file "statistics.csv" (list meet meet-agg meetown meetown-agg meetother meetother-agg coopown coopown-agg coopother coopother-agg defown defown-agg defother defother-agg)`
error: Extension exception: Expected a list of lists, but 1016 was one of the elements.

could someone help me with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Lu! Welcome to StackOverflow! I've tried to guess what your problem was in my answer below, but in general, a good rule of thumb when asking questions is to try to give a bit more detail about what's going on. In your case, telling us what error messages your are getting instead of just stating that things don't work would have helped us diagnose your problem better. You can always edit your question and add more details if you want.

Answer (score 3):

About:

```
csv:to-file "patches.csv" [ (list xcor ycor cluster-number) ] of patches
```

I'm guessing the only problem is that you're trying to use `xcor` and `ycor`, which are turtle variables, instead of `pxcor` and `pycor`, which are patches variables. You need:

```
csv:to-file "patches.csv" [ (list pxcor pycor cluster-number) ] of patches
```

As for this one:

```
csv:to-file "statistics.csv" (list meet meet-agg meetown meetown-agg meetother meetother-agg coopown coopown-agg coopother coopother-agg defown defown-agg defother defother-agg)
```

one thing to keep in mind is that `csv:to-file` expects a "list of lists", and your code produces a single list, which is likely the problem. If all those variables are global variables, and you just want them in a single row in your CSV file, you could just wrap your list in another list:

```
csv:to-file "statistics.csv" (list (list meet meet-agg meetown meetown-agg meetother meetother-agg coopown coopown-agg coopother coopother-agg defown defown-agg defother defother-agg))
```

But it's hard to diagnose your problem precisely without more information. Can you tell us what makes you think it's not working? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! these are exactly what I need! and sorry about the unclear question.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help!

Comment: @LuYang - Hi Lu, welcome to Stack Overflow! If Nicolas' answer has solved your issue, please click the little check mark box next to his answer to mark this question as closed.